# Show different lines in files

Tags: python

I have found a script which shows different lines in the file NEW.txt which do not exist in OLD.txt file. It works fine, but the problem is that script is messing the lines order when I get the output. This is the script:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\AMB\NEW.txt') as f, open(r'C:\Users\AMB\OLD.txt') as f2:
    lines1 = set(map(str.rstrip, f))
    s = str(lines1.difference(map(str.rstrip, f2)))                                                   
s = s.replace(',', '\n').replace("'", '').replace("{", '').replace("}", '')

print(s)
```

So let's suppose that this is the OLD.txt content:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
cccccccccccc
eeeeeeeeeeee
```

And this is the NEW.txt content:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccc
dddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeee
hhhhhhhhhhhh
```

I would like to get this output:

```
bbbbbbbbbbbb
dddddddddddd
hhhhhhhhhhhh
```

But I am getting a random line order, for example:

```
dddddddddddd
bbbbbbbbbbbb
hhhhhhhhhhhh
```

(the output is random, and not always the same)

Is there a way to keep the order for output lines in NEW.txt file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're using `set` to de-duplicate the data, hence why the final order is random

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know the reason because it is happening but I would like to find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `set` and do all the operations using `list`.

See this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-two-lists/) for more help.

Solution:

```py
s = ""
with open(r'C:\Users\AMB\NEW.txt') as f, open(r'C:\Users\AMB\OLD.txt') as f2:
    lines1 = list(map(str.rstrip, f)) #list of words in f
    lines2 = list(map(str.rstrip, f2)) #list of words in f2
    
    #finds the difference between both lists
    diff = [i for i in lines1 + lines2 if i not in lines1 or i not in lines2]
    
    for words in diff:
        s = s + words + '\n' #Appending all words to form a single string

s = s.rstrip() #remove last line whitespace
print(s)
```